# Tag synonyms: Inconsistencies

Tags: bug, tag-management

Many tags have synonyms. My understanding is that there are "primary" tags with one or more synonyms. If somebody uses a synonym, then the this tag is automatically replaced by the primary tag.

"Synonym" tags should not occur in the tag list at the bottom of a question, but they are searchable. For example, [dot-product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dot-product) is [a synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/inner-products/synonyms) for [inner-products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inner-products). The tag [dot-product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dot-product) is never visible in  tag lists associated to questions, but if one searches for it, one gets all questions with the tag [inner-products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inner-products).

There are some exceptions from this rule. Here is a list:

| Synonym | No. of occurences | Target | No. of occurences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| finite-automata | 235 | automata | 1841 |
| holomorphic-functions | 713 | complex-analysis | 51709 |
| finite-difference-methods | 106 | finite-differences | 814 |
| predicate-logic | 4145 | first-order-logic | 5432 |
| fixed-point-iteration | 126 | fixed-point-theorems | 1931 |
| banach-fixed-point | 106 | fixed-point-theorems | 1931 |
| least-common-multiple | 332 | gcd-and-lcm | 2684 |
| st-connectivity | 3 | graph-connectivity | 370 |
| integration-by-parts | 229 | integration | 73522 |
| span | 177 | linear-algebra | 126901 |
| semiclassical-analysis | 16 | microlocal-analysis | 75 |
| linear-fractional-transformation | 47 | mobius-transformation | 832 |
| gaussian | 493 | normal-distribution | 7617 |
| elementary-probability | 65 | probability | 105777 |
| legendre-symbol | 302 | quadratic-residues | 808 |
| jacobi-symbol | 37 | quadratic-residues | 808 |
| proof-verification | 22801 | solution-verification | 21394 |
| perfect-squares | 21 | square-numbers | 1340 |

In these cases there are questions with one of these tags and both these tags. Examples:

- [Wavefront set of a distribution and elliptic points on a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4641267) : Tag microlocal-analysis
- [Creating a bounded operator from an unbounded symbol ? - discussion around the Calderon-Vaillancourt theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4479345) : Tags microlocal-analysis and semiclassical-analysis
- [$O_{\mathcal{S}'\rightarrow \mathcal{S}}(h^\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/457627) : Tag semiclassical-analysis

**I suggest that this should be corrected if it can be done automatically. Doing it manually is of course no option except in very few cases.**

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204472/160917, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296984/160917, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131506/160917, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135409/160917

Comment: @D.W.: It is still strange. The semiclassical-analysis -> microlocal-analysis synonym was created in April 2021, therefore (as I understand it) it should not have been possible to add it as an additional tag to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4479345/42969 in July 2022.

Comment: @MartinR AFAICT this synonym was *suggested* in April 2021, but created (approved) in August 2023: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=semiclassical-analysis

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Interesting. I looked here https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms (filter for "semi"), where it says “Created: April 21, 2021” – Apparently “Created” is not the date when the synonym became active (approved). That is confusing IMO.

Comment: @MartinR Perhaps this post on [meta.se] clarifies things a bit: [What does the column "created" in the list of tag synonyms mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341965)

Comment: Here is a related SEDE query: Tag synonyms where both tags have some questions - on the [main site](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1314919/tag-synonyms-where-both-tags-have-some-questions) and on [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1314919/tag-synonyms-where-both-tags-have-some-questions).
I see there only three instances not listed in the current revisions of the question, namely 
[congruences](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1190392/find-questions-containing-the-given-tag?tagName=congruences), 
expectation and stability-in-odes.

Comment: I suspect that those examples you list are tags where a synonym was created and the two tags haven't been merged. 
This has some consequences for searching in those tags: [Tag synonyms and searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382271).

Comment: @MartinSleziak You are certainly right that a synonym was created and the two tags have not been merged. But in most cases they were merged and in my question I suggested to catch up with merging.